# Optimizing If Else for Date variables in R

Tags: r, if-statement, optimization

I am working with a dataset with information about cities with Covid and I would like to add a variable if city x in date t was in quaratine, I created an ifelse code but it takes a lot of time for the 2.3MM observations I have.

My dataset looks like this

```
City     Date
a      2020-03-04    
b      2020-03-04
a      2020-03-05    
b      2020-03-05
a      2020-03-06   
b      2020-03-06 
a      2020-03-07 
b      2020-03-07
```

And my code is this

```
library(data.table
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(quarantine = 0)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(quarantine = fifelse(City = "a",
                              fifelse(Date > as.Date("2020-03-04") &
                                      Date <= as.Date("2020-03-06"), 1, 0),
                              quarantine) %>%
   mutate(quarantine = fifelse(City = "b",
                              fifelse(Date > as.Date("2020-03-05") &
                                      Date <= as.Date("2020-03-07"), 1, 0),
                              quarantine)
```

And that repeated until I complete the 34 cities I have, it is a really long code but I don't know how to optimize it because every city has a different date for quarantine so I don't know if I can loop it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where do you have your quarantine dates? I don't understand the 2 comparisons : isn't > 2020-03-05 & <=2020-03-06 same as == 2020-03-06? For a start, you should vectorised your code (no ifelse) and, as you load `data.table` , just go with `data.table` code, not a mix with `dplyr`

Comment: The quarantine dates I took them from wikipedia.

Comment: then I think first of all you need to put them in a data.frame city/quarantineStartDate/quarantineEndDate which you can use to avoid having 34 lines of code

Comment: And then a code to search if the date is in between those dates?

Comment: yes, a vectorised one (no ifelses)